# Using waypoints to find the route

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, url-routing

I am working on finding the route between two points using javascript, google maps api v3 and pgoruting. Now I have the following method which works fine when I give just one waypoint. BUT it does not work when I jave more than one waypoint. The format when there is more than one waypoint is delimeted with this symbol `'|'`. Therefore for example: `36.762121,14.7866553|35.988777778,14.655444333`

The javascript method is the following:

```
   function calcRoute() {

        var all_nodes = document.getElementById('result').innerHTML;
        var node = all_nodes.split("|");

        var start = node[0];
        var end = node[node.length - 1];
        var wpts = [];

        for (var i = 1; i < node.length-1; i++) {
            wpts.push({
                location:node[i],
                stopover:true
            });
        }

        var request = {
            origin: start,
            destination: end,
            waypoints: wpts,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        };

        directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            } else {
                alert('No route found');
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Do you have an example that _doesn't_ work?  This works fine: `36.762121,14.7866553|35.988777778,14.655444333`

Comment: As does [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions-waypoints_fromString.html): `36.762121,14.7866553|Milan,Italy|Zurich,Switzerland|35.988777778,14.655444333`

Comment: I have tried the above examples within the function I have posted and I had no results. @geocodezip

Comment: Compare your version to [mine](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions-waypoints_fromString.html).  The only difference is where that string is coming from.  Since you didn't post that part of your page, I didn't copy it.

Comment: It is strange sometimes it works and sometimes its not working.

Comment: Can you provide example coordinates that don't work?

Comment: 35.8985889284545,14.5055646878199|35.8986975284544,14.5056558878199|35.8988670284544,14.5058167878199|35.8990365284545,14.5061117878199"@geocodezip

Comment: It does [work better](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions-waypoints_fromStringA.html) if you translate the coordinates into google.maps.LatLng objects rather than counting on the directions service to recognize that string as coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Actual thats incorrect waypoints are arrays of location:LatLng and stopover:true or false and they do not use the pipe delimiter please refer to [Waypoints](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Waypoints)

Comment: I have posted my modified javascript code as indicated by the link, but still when I give it more than one waypoint, no routes will be displayed. Any idea why is happening? @David Chase

Comment: please post any new or modified code, that way i can help you based on that

Comment: A [waypoint](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsWaypoint) can be an object containing a location which is a google.maps.LatLng or a string, but when it is a string, I believe it is expected to be an address, not two coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

As previously suggested, it might help to get a google object for the location and it may also help to supply the lat and long as two seperate entities.

```
    for (var i = 1; i < node.length-1; i = i + 1) {
        node[i] = node[i].split(',');
        wpts.push({
            location:new google.maps.LatLng(node[i][0], node[i][1]),
            stopover:true
        });
    }
```

Comment: Of course. If the split worked, it would only work for lat longs and not textual entries so may be moot. Unless of course the text has a comma